# JS table search/sort/filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem when searching in tables. Like I tried list.js, but it didn't work. I found this piece of code but that didn't work either.

```
var $rows = $('#table tr');
        $('#search').keyup(function() {
            var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

            $rows.show().filter(function() {
                var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                return !~text.indexOf(val);
            }).hide();
        });
```

And i test that and the function won't even trigger. I tried that with alert. I can't see a problem, but I'am not as good with JS/jQuery, so maybe I'am doing mistake somewhere :/

BTW: This is Table HTML:

```
<table id="table" class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Jméno</th><th>Příjmení</th>
        <th>Adresa</th><th>Datum narození</th>
        <th>Pohlaví</th><th>Připomenutí</th>
        <th>Poslední kontakt</th><th>Skupina</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style='cursor:pointer;' onclick='window.location.href = "./mf_contact_form.php?cid=168"'>
        <td>
            <span style='margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width:1px; background:#da00ff; float:left; margin-left: -20px; height: 100%;'></span><img src='[HIDDEN]' style='width: 64px; height: 64px; border-radius: 50%;'>
        </td>
        <td>
            Test
        </td>
        <td>
            Test
        </td>
        <td>
            Test
        </td>
        <td>
            5615-12-06
        </td>
        <td>
            Muž
        </td>
        <td>
            3x za týden
        </td>
        <td>
            Žádná historie
        </td>
        <td>
            gjh
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And it is generated by PHP, but I don't think that would cause that problem.

Comment: Is `#seach` input actually available when you are executing your code?
Try  `console.log($('#search').length)`. If length is 0. You need to either put script tag at the end of the body (atleast below the input and table), or use dom ready event `$(function(){/*your code here*/})`

Comment: That work, thanks a lot.